# OOP : Naming a class

Tags: oop, classname

In my application I have a Market with a bunch of Levels. Each level has Goods and Supply Chain Operations. Now, I'm stuck figuring out how to name a family of classes that populate Levels with these entities. I know that a name is important in a sesnse that a proper one makes code self-commented. Since stuff like Builder, Creator, Factory, Provider is more of a wiring classes, I'm out of ideas. Right now I use Market_Level_Goods_Filler, but it feels odd. Any suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Personally I like to use the [Command/Query pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-query_separation) as a way of dividing and managing these types of classes.

In this context your class would be a command. Either way I'd be naming my classes to describe what they actually do.

What does your class do?

Perhaps `PopulateLevelsForMarket` or `PopulateMarketLevels`? (PopulateLevelsForMarketCommand if using the Command/Query paradigm).

If you're finding it hard to name your class because it does a variety of different things you'll want to start thinking about breaking up the class so that the focus is one a single set of operations.

Think [SRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) at the class level.

Answer (score 0):

Your description makes me think that `Market` and `Level` make up a Gang of Four Composite pattern.  Is that correct?

I would say that a `LevelBuilder` or `LevelLoader` would be appropriate.  I don't understand your "more of a wiring classes" [sic] objection.  Populate sounds like a creation verb to me.

Comment: Market aggregates levels, they are not composites. I don't need any sort of nesting.